# general jenkins and subversion info

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have used subversion in the past to work on group projects and just heard of "jenkins" which  I know nothing about. Can someone please tell me the differences between them and why jenkins is so popular? just looking for some insight into their respective purposes.

Comment: In one sentence: Automated builds (and tests) magically happen everytime a member of your team commits code into subversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion is a version control system that stores your code. Jenkins is a web-based build manager and continuous integration server.

An example of how they might work together is you would check your changed code into subversion. Subversion would then notify Jenkins of the change. Jenkins would check the code out of subversion, run a build, perhaps run some tests and then perhaps email the results to the development team.